# Creating subscription plans with Braintree or regular PayPal in React.js

Tags: reactjs, paypal, braintree, paypal-subscriptions

I'm trying to learn how to make subscription plans with API calls inReact.js. I'm just wondering which technology I should use to learn and make my project happen.

Should I start to learn the Braintree API methods or Paypal subscription API calls?

Also, what is a really big difference between Braintree and Paypal? I couldn't get a really good explanation of what each does on the internet. everything is a short nonsense description. I feel people who really have their hands dirty in these technologies have better answers.

Answer (score 0):

> what is a really big difference between Braintree and Paypal?

Braintree has more features because it requires approval for use in live. So if you are considering Braintree, it's a matter of whether your business can be approved for it or not.